# Oracle: Update history table TYPE_ID with correct TYPE_ID one from non-history table

Tags: sql, oracle, copy

We have two tables

```
COI_EVENTS
H_COI_EVENTS
```

The only columns relevant are `EVENT_ID` and `TYPE_ID`. `EVENT_ID` is the PK column, `TYPE_ID` links to another table (irrelevant here).

The `COI_EVENTS` table contains the current event data. Every update via application copies the `COI_EVENTS` data to `H_COI_EVENTS` for history.

Some of the `H_COI_EVENTS` linked to the current event contain different `TYPE_ID`s than what is in `COI_EVENTS`, which is messed up data.

I want to copy the `TYPE_ID` from `COI_EVENTS` to `H_COI_EVENTS` for all history rows where the `TYPE_ID` don't match. (maybe the solution can even just copy the non-history `TYPE_ID` to `H_COI_EVENTS`).

I tried

```
update H_COI_EVENTS heo
  set heo.TYPE_ID = e.TYPE_ID
  where exists (select e.TYPE_ID
                  from COI_EVENTS e
                  join H_COI_EVENTS he
                    on he.EVENT_ID = e.EVENT_ID
                  where he.TYPE_ID <> e.TYPE_ID);
```

but this results in some Syntax error, because FROM is not allowed here. Another try

```
update H_COI_EVENTS heo
  set heo.TYPE_ID = (select e1.TYPE_ID
                       from COI_EVENTS e1
                       join H_COI_EVENTS he1
                         on heo.EVENT_ID = e1.EVENT_ID
                       where e1.EVENT_ID = heo.EVENT_ID)
  where exists (select e.TYPE_ID
                  from COI_EVENTS e
                  join H_COI_EVENTS he
                    on he.EVENT_ID = e.EVENT_ID
                  where he.TYPE_ID <> e.TYPE_ID);
```

gives me an error:

```
Fehler beim Start in Zeile 22 in Befehl:
update H_COI_EVENTS heo
set heo.TYPE_ID = ( select e1.TYPE_ID from COI_EVENTS e1 join H_COI_EVENTS he1 on heo.EVENT_ID = e1.EVENT_ID where e1.EVENT_ID = heo.EVENT_ID )
where exists ( select e.TYPE_ID
from COI_EVENTS e
join H_COI_EVENTS he on he.EVENT_ID = e.EVENT_ID
where he.TYPE_ID <> e.TYPE_ID)
Fehlerbericht:
SQL-Fehler: ORA-01407: Aktualisieren von ("ABN_12C"."H_COI_EVENTS"."TYPE_ID") zu NULL nicht möglich
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

**Update**:

An even easier approach to simple copy the ID to all history rows is:

```
update H_COI_EVENTS heo
set heo.TYPE_ID = ( select ei.TYPE_ID from COI_EVENTS ei where ei.EVENT_ID = heo.EVENT_ID )
```

However, Oracle chokes with:

```
Fehler beim Start in Zeile 33 in Befehl:
update H_COI_EVENTS heo
set heo.TYPE_ID = ( select ei.TYPE_ID from COI_EVENTS ei where ei.EVENT_ID = heo.EVENT_ID )
Fehlerbericht:
SQL-Fehler: ORA-01407: Aktualisieren von ("ABN_12C"."H_COI_EVENTS"."TYPE_ID") zu NULL nicht möglich
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I don't get it.

---

How do I achieve what I described?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include some sample data in your two tables, along with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I find MERGE much easier to work with than correlated update (for which I invariably need to dig up SQL syntax guide to get right).

```
MERGE INTO H_COI_EVENTS H
USING (SELECT EVENT_ID, TYPE_ID FROM COI_EVENTS) C
ON C.EVENT_ID = H.EVENT_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET H.TYPE_ID = C.TYPE_ID
WHERE H.TYPE_ID <> C.TYPE_ID;
```